# var not getting implicit value

Tags: c#, asp.net, var, anonymous-types

I just came across the code below:

```
public void ListControls(ControlCollection controls, List<Control> controlsFound)
{
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        if (control is IAttributeAccessor)
        {
            controlsFound.Add(control); //Error (Invalid argument to Add method)
            ListControls(control.Controls, controlsFound);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives an error as above:

If I change `var` in `foreach` to `Control` then it works. The reason is that the `Add` method was expecting `Control` as parameter. But I think var should have been implicitly replaced by `Control`, right?

Comment: `ControlCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<Control>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesnt because [ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` not the generic `IEnumerable<Control>` so when you enumerate it without providing the type, you get `object`

Comment: As it is a ControlCollection then it must have collection of Control and should have been know to compiler, why it is not like that?

Comment: @Imad The compiler knows a collection contains items of type `T`, *if* that collection implements `IEnumerable<T>`. `ControlCollection` does not implement that interface, so the compiler does not know which type the items are.

Comment: *You* deduce that `ControlCollection` contains instances of `Control` because of its name. But how would the compiler know?

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ will work:

```
public void ListControls(ControlCollection controls, List<Control> controlsFound)
    {
        foreach (var control in controls.OfType<Control>())
        {
            if (control is IAttributeAccessor)
            {
                controlsFound.Add(control); //Error (Invalid argument to Add method)
                ListControls(control.Controls, controlsFound);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, sort of LINQ, in that the [extension method on `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is in the `System.LINQ` namespace, but to call this "LINQ" is a bit misleading.